# Calloc could not allocate memory. Importing SQL Table to R

Tags: r

Hi I'm having issues on connecting to SQL Server Table.
It says could not allocate memory.
Below is the code and error message.

```
> mycon <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=AIGI-TWVIRSQL01;
+                            Database=ImageRightTRN;Trusted_Connection=Yes")
> 
> dataT <- sqlQuery(mycon, "Select * FROM dbo.StepRootDef")
Error in odbcQuery(channel, query, rows_at_time) : 
  'Calloc' could not allocate memory (214748364800 of 1 bytes)
```

Is it because the Table is too large?
How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Take a look to ff package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html along with ffbase and ffbase2. You can use read.dbi.ffdf to get data from a db: read.dbi.ffdf(query, dbConnect.args = list(drv = ..., host, port, dbname, user, password))

Comment: So in my case the code should look like this. ff::read.dbi.ffdf(query="Select * from dbo.StepRootDef", dbConnect.args= list(drv=dbDriver("SQL Server"),dbname="ImageRightTRN")) Question where should I include my Server in the code? Server=AIGI-TWVIRSQL01.

Comment: in the host parameter: host = ...

Comment: read.dbi.ffdf(query="Select * FROM dbo.StepRootDef", 
dbConnect.args= list(drv=dbDriver("SQL Server"),host="AIGI-TWVIRSQL01",dbname="ImageRightTRN")) But I had error Error: Couldn't find driver SQL Server. Looked in:
* global namespace
* in package called SQL Server
* in package called RSQL Server

Comment: I usually use MySQL, haven't deal with SQL Server connection problems. Which library are you using to connect to SQL Server? Try DBI.